# get the res data from node-geocode

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-geocoder

I'm still learning about javascript especially nodejs, and I want to get the data of city from res of the node-geocoder. Here's my code:

```
const
    nodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

const
    tes = require('./tes');

let
    options = {
        provider: 'google',
        httpAdapter: 'https',
        apiKey: myapi,
        formatter: null
    };

let geocoder = nodeGeocoder(options);

geocoder.reverse({
    lat: tes.lat,
    lon: tes.lon
})
.then( res => {
    return city = res[0].administrativeLevels.level1long;
})
.catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
})

console.log(city);
```

Comment: You can't access city outside then callback/promise , you need to do things inside then function

Answer (score 0):

**Either use callback function or do things inside .then() promise**

```
const
    nodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

const
    tes = require('./tes');

let
    options = {
        provider: 'google',
        httpAdapter: 'https',
        apiKey: myapi,
        formatter: null
    };

let geocoder = nodeGeocoder(options);

geocoder.reverse({
    lat: tes.lat,
    lon: tes.lon
})
.then( res => {
    city = res[0].administrativeLevels.level1long;

    //do here whatever you want   

})
.catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Or make callback function

```
function getCity(callback){

 geocoder.reverse({
        lat: tes.lat,
        lon: tes.lon
    })
    .then( res => {
        city = res[0].administrativeLevels.level1long;
        callback(null, city);

    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    })
}
```

use above function

```
 getCity(function(err, city){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);

  }else{
    console.log(city);
  }

})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,
and how to export the city so I can use the value in another function?

Comment: use function getCity(callback){ } and call it as above